# ExcelJS - Strict-mode does not allow assignment to undefined variables: regeneratorRuntime

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, devextreme, exceljs

I'm using DevExtreme dxDataGrid and I want to export data to an xlsx-file. They have implemented it using ExcelJs:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Utils/excelExporter/#exportDataGridoptions

As explained I just need to reference the following libs:

```
<head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.1.1/exceljs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
        <!-- reference the DevExtreme sources here -->
</head>
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 with VS 2022. For this I'm using the [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) to bundle libs like jQuery, DevExtreme and ExcelJs.

I have downloaded ExcelJs (like I have done for jQuery etc.) with libman.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "jquery@3.6.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/lib/jquery/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "exceljs@4.3.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/lib/exceljs/",
      "files": [
        "exceljs.min.js",
        "exceljs.js"
      ]
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "FileSaver.js@2.0.5",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/lib/FileSaver.js/"
    },
    {
      "provider": "cdnjs",
      "library": "babel-polyfill@6.26.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/js/lib/babel-polyfill/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I have added ExcelJs to my bundleconfig.json:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/bundle/LibraryBundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js",
      "wwwroot/js/lib/babel-polyfill/polyfill.js",
      "wwwroot/js/lib/exceljs/exceljs.js",
      "wwwroot/js/lib/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js"

    ]
  }
]
```

Then I'm getting following error in Visual Studio:

> Strict-mode does not allow assignment to undefined variables: regeneratorRuntime

`strict-mode` is defined in ExcelJS and also many other lib's I don't understand why I'm getting this error and how can I fix it. I was not able to find any similar issue at Github-ExcelJs and it doesn't look like that they are not really supporting their open issues. Because of that I'm tried to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I am still on ExcelJS 4.2.1, but I was running into a similar issue.

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1411#issuecomment-977578401) on an ExcelJS issue, in the exceljs.js file, this is the offending block of code:

```javascript
try {
  regeneratorRuntime = runtime;
} catch (accidentalStrictMode) {
  // This module should not be running in strict mode, so the above
  // assignment should always work unless something is misconfigured. Just
  // in case runtime.js accidentally runs in strict mode, we can escape
  // strict mode using a global Function call. This could conceivably fail
  // if a Content Security Policy forbids using Function, but in that case
  // the proper solution is to fix the accidental strict mode problem. If
  // you've misconfigured your bundler to force strict mode and applied a
  // CSP to forbid Function, and you're not willing to fix either of those
  // problems, please detail your unique predicament in a GitHub issue.
  Function("r", "regeneratorRuntime = r")(runtime);
}
```

NEW workaround from [Phoniex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222641/exceljs-strict-mode-does-not-allow-assignment-to-undefined-variables-regenera/73256148#comment129637016_73256148) is to create a file with simply

```javascript
var regeneratorRuntime;
```

in it, and include it before the exceljs.js file.

OLD workaround is to replace the assignment in the `try` block with:

```javascript
window.regeneratorRuntime = runtime;
```

Comment: This will fix it temporary, but I'm using libman.json => the file will be replaced everytime you make change in libman.json. Adding this all the time is not very suitable - but at the moment the only solution...

Comment: I am also using libman.json, but [according to this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/368#issuecomment-421434700), "restore on build is not the primary scenario we designed for. The default behavior is that a user uses LibMan to download the files into their repo (and periodically to update them), but the files are checked in by default." So, I have my project configured not to restore the libraries automatically.

In the long term, I think this is something that the ExcelJS people need to fix.

Comment: Anyway modifying libs is not very suitable. I tried to switch from Bundler & Minifier, but this causes a lot of other issue. I don't have much time to search for such issues at the moment. So I have fixed it for the Bundler & Minifier with an additional js-file where I just declare the `var regeneratorRuntime;` and then I have added it to my bundle. But you are right ExcelJS should fix this.

Comment: I like your workaround much better than mine. Now I don't have to maintain a custom copy of the library with the one line changed. I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Thanks!